# Invoking doxygen search from the console

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I'm using doxygen in a C++ project under Linux. Searching is possible using the search box on the documentation main page, but is there a way to call the search from the command line? For example, by using something like `firefox myHelp.html/+search for myClass+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to start a browser with a search result from your doxygen documentation?

The URL to perform a search within a doxygen documentation page has the form:

```
 ...Doxygen/html/search.php?query=searchterm
```

So you could try something like

```
 firefox file:///somepath/Doxygen/html/search.php?query=searchterm
```

However, I am not sure if that solves your problem.

Besides you can use typical command line tools to find terms in your file system:

```
 grep -R searchterm
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - I'm using client-side search as opposed to server-side so the search.php route is unavailable,,, (SEARCHENGINE=YES, SERVER_BASED_SEARCH=NO).  Is it possible to hook into the client-side javascript/dhtml search engine?